# django REST framework nested serializer and POST nested JSON with files

Tags: javascript, django, http, vue.js, django-rest-framework

**How do I send a POST request with nested data including files (images) to django REST nested serializers?**

Given this JS object:

```
bookData: {
    title: 'Anne of Green Gables',
    coverImage: File(123456),
    pages: 123,
    author: {
        name: 'Lucy Maud Montgomery',
        born: 1874,
        profilepicture_set: [
            {file: File(234567), description: 'Young L. M. Montgomery'},
            {file: File(234568), description: 'Old L. M. Montgomery}
        ],
        quote_set: [
            {text: "I'm so glad I live in a world where there are Octobers."},
            {text: "True friends are always together in spirit."},
        ]
    },

}
```

I want to send a POST request to my django REST API (I use VueJS on frontend, but this does not really matter).

```
# views.py
class CreateBookView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateBookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

# serializers.py
class CreateBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CreateAuthorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'pages', 'author')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        author_data = validated_data.pop('author')
        uploader = self.context['request'].user
        book = Book.objects.create(uploader=uploader, **validated_data)

        Author.objects.create(book=book, **author_data)

        return book


# models.py
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self, **author_data):
        quotes_data = author_data.pop('quote_set')
        photos_data = author_data.pop('profilepicture_set')

        author = Author(**author_data)
        author.save()

        for quote_data in quotes_data:
            Quote.objects.create(author=author, **quote_data)

        for photo_data in photos_data :
            ProfilePicture.objects.create(author=author, **photo_data)

        return author

## Skipping the CreateAuthorSerializer, Quote and ProfilePicture Managers as they are analogous.
## Assume one Author can only write one Book (OneToOneField). No need to look the name up for existing Authors.
```

---

**EDIT**

I wanted to add some info on how I send the data in the frontend in VueJS.

```
sendData(){
    var fd = new FormData()
    var bookData = {
        title: this.$store.getters.title, # 'Anne of Green Gables"
        coverImage: this.$store.getters.coverImage, # File(somesize)
        pages: this.$store.getters.pages, # 123
        author: this.$store.getters.author, # nested object 
        ...
    }
    fd = objectToFormData(bookData, fd) # external function, see below
    this.$http.post('api/endpoint/create/', fd, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
        }
    }).then(...)
}
```

The `sendData()` is invoked on button click. 
The `objectToFormData` is an external lib from npm [(click)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata) that transforms the nested object into flat form.

The problem with this solution (as well as @Saji Xavier's solution) is that the `request.data` contains an ugly QueryDict which is far from the original `bookData` object structure and is not accepted by the REST serializer (namely, the `author` field is missing - which is true, the object has been flattened).

```
<QueryDict: {
'title': ['Anne of Green Gables'], 
'coverImage':[InMemoryUploadedFile: cover.jpg (image/jpeg)],
'pages': ['123'], 
'name': ['Lucy Maud Montgomery'], 
'born': ['1874'],
'profilepicture_set[][description]': ['Young L. M. Montgomery', 'Old L. M. Montgomery'], 
'profilepicture_set[][file]': [
    InMemoryUploadedFile: young.jpg (image/jpeg), 
    InMemoryUploadedFile: old.jpg (image/jpeg)
    ],
'quote_set[][text]': [
    "I'm so glad I live in a world where there are Octobers.",
    "True friends are always together in spirit."
    ]
}>
```

How do I deal with it now? It seems sooooo ugly. What I can think of is to overwrite the `create()` function.

```
class CreateBookView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    (...)
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book_data = {}
        book_data['title'] = request.data['title']
        book_data['pages'] = request.data['pages']
        book_data['cover_image'] = request.data['coverImage']
        book_data['author'] = {}
        book_data['author']['name'] = request.data['name']
        book_data['author']['born'] = request.data['born']
        (...)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=book_data)
        (...)
```

This is extremely ugly solution, ineffective for models with multitude of fields and several levels of nestedness (this book/author is just a toy example).

How should I handle it? Do i change the way of POSTing (to get a nice `request.data` format) or do I handle this ugly one?

Answer (score 0):

According DRF [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#file-upload-fields),

> Most parsers, such as e.g. JSON don't support file uploads. Django's
>   regular FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS are used for handling uploaded files.

One option is to use Javascript FormData API to send multipart data (works with VueJS/AngularJS)

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('title', 'Anne of Green Gables')
fd.append('author_name', 'Lucy Maud Montgomery')
fd.append('author_profilepicture_set', files[])
$http.post('url', fd, {
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
});
```

Comment: this does not address my problem - I managed to send the data, but the request format is very uncomfortable for processing by DRF serializers.

Comment: multipart will create problem for serializers, so my suggestion is not to use serializer functionalities like (validataion, save etc), instead use request.POST.get(data) and save the files in the server (or handle the file separate and let serializer handle rest of the data)

Comment: I know it is not cleaner solution, couldn't find any other solution when i was looking for the same and we have to go for FormData approach.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can get it to work this way, I just... dont feel good doing it this way :) Prone to errors, prone to incompatibility after model updates... Ugh :X